# Python's os.chdir() and os.getcwd() mismatch when using tempfile.mkdtemp() on Mac OSX Lion

Tags: python, macos, filesystems

I'm not sure if this is a bug or a feature, but when I change the directory using `os.chdir()` to the one generated with `tempfile.mkdtemp()` then `os.getcwd()` reports a directory with `/private` prefix.

The following code illustrates this:

```
In [1]: import os, tempfile

In [2]: d = tempfile.mkdtemp()

In [3]: d
Out[3]: '/var/folders/s4/grpfgn297hjgnfws3tl_gnt80000gn/T/tmpmfNUYz'

In [4]: os.chdir( d )

In [5]: os.getcwd()
Out[5]: '/private/var/folders/s4/grpfgn297hjgnfws3tl_gnt80000gn/T/tmpmfNUYz'
```

Could someone please explain why this is so?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`/var` is a symlink to `/private/var`

```
$ ls -l /var
lrwxr-xr-x@ 1 root  wheel  11 Dec  2  2011 /var -> private/var
```

`tempfile` is just using the environment `TMPDIR` variable to prefix the path location, so its just a string. But `os.getcwd()` is resolving the absolute location:

```
$ echo $TMPDIR
/var/folders/04/kc575q1n6x9drkwxyfljg5zw0000gn/T/
```

Comment: Thanks - is there a way to fix that behaviour, i.e. get the same path which was passed to `os.chdir()` when calling `os.getcwd()` ?

Comment: Not by that exact approach. Once you change directories, you are then inside of the location that the link points to. Meaning you are not really in "/var". You are in "/private/var". You would just need to keep using the original string path as a root.

Comment: I turns out that the way to make this behave properly is to run what `mkdtemp()` returns by `os.path.realpath()` (I have originally tried `os.path.abspath()` and it didn't work). @jdi Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.